# is there a way to speed up queries on self referential

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

so suppose I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 A, table1 B where A.id = B.id;
```

even if there is an index on id on table1, it would still scan the entire table...is there a way to speed this up so that it doesn't scan the entire table?

Comment: It's scanning the entire table because every record in the table is going to meet the criteria. I assume this was a simplification of your actual problem, but I think you went too simple and it's no longer a good representation.

Comment: "even if there is an index on id on table1, it would still scan the entire table..." --- yes, because you select everything from `table1`. "is there a way to speed this up so that it doesn't scan the entire table" --- add `WHERE`

Comment: Is "id" ever NULL?  That would be the one case where this would act as a filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I do not have your execution plan in front of my, this is actually only scanning `TableA` most likely, and the reason for that is because you have no other conditions on `TableA`. It should be seeking on `TableB` at this time just because it's statistical. Now, if you were to provide another condition for `TableA`, and that condition met an index, you would find that it was not scanning the entire table.

To further that, if the index on `TableA` was a covered index for the query it would actually never even read a data page for `TableA`.

And to further that, if there were a foreign key constraint between `TableA` and `TableB` and you weren't reading anything more from `TableB` than the id field it would also never read a data page.

And to further that, even if you did need data from `TableB`, if that data were on an index it still wouldn't have to read a data page.

But finally, because you're selecting `*`, it's unlikely this will ever be a very efficient query because it's selecting all columns from **both** tables.

I hope that wasn't too long winded but I wanted to make sure that you knew where I was coming from.